# freeform: give freeform a name

Tags: solspace-freeform

I want to give my form a name but it's not appearing

something like

```
{exp:freeform:form 

   name='myform'

   collection=""
   required="
   return=""
   template=""
   send_user_email="no"

}
```

gives
 
but not a string with name='myform'

Answer (score 1):

I believe the appropriate syntax is `form:name='myform'`

It looks like you're using an older version of Freeform (since you're using the collection parameter), so you may need to dig up the docs for that version, or update.